# Display an ArrayList on a jsp page

Tags: java, list, jsp, select, arraylist

I have this CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) project on jsp. I am not using Servlet since I have just one table I created myself.
I wrote all code regarding display-all-users inside the DB (visualizzaUtenti() method). Still, I just don't know how to invoke the function in the jsp scriplet. Connection with jdbc works fine on my localhost: it is inside an encapsulated class called DBUtiliy. Delete and Insert queries work too. Anyone can help? Here's my code below.

```
public List<Utente> visualizzaUtenti() {
    List<Utente> utenti = new ArrayList<Utente>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connessione.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbldatiutenti");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Utente utente = new Utente();
            utente.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            utente.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            utente.setCognome(rs.getString("cognome"));   
            utente.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            utente.setGenere(rs.getString("genere"));
            System.out.println("Visualizzazione effettuata");
            utenti.add(utente);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return utenti;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unsure whether I understand correctly. You want to know how to call your `visualizzaUtenti()` function in your JSP?

Comment: Yes. I want to call it (sorry for my English) and display all results on my jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting such issues, request you to do some search yourself, there are numerous solution readily available.

Use jsp:useBean and c:forEach loop as below and initialize bean value in setUtenti(),

```
<jsp:useBean id="ClassList" scope="page" class="ClassName" />
<c:forEach var="title" items="${ClassList.utenti}">
 <c:out value="${title}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSTL core library for c:forEach tag which you will see later in the sample.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Do the imports needed

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="your.package.DBUtiliy"%>
<%@page import="your.package.Utente"%>

<%
    // make an object of the class
    DBUtiliy dbUtiliy= new DBUtiliy();
    List<Utente> listOfUtente= dbUtiliy.visualizzaUtenti();
%>
```

Then you just need to iterate over the items

```
<div>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="<%=listOfUtente%>" var="utente">

                <li>${utente.someProperty}</li>

            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a servlet instead of using scriptlets in JSP, in wich you will do the following:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SampleServlet", urlPatterns = {"/sample"})
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

//your visualizzaUtenti() method code goes here

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
 request.setAttribute("utenti", visualizzaUtenti());
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
                   .getRequestDispatcher("/YourJSPPage.jsp");  
   if (dispatcher != null){  
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
   }
 }
}
```

And in your JSP you can do the following:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Id</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Cognome</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Genere</th></tr>
  <c:forEach var="utente" items="${utenti}">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${utente.id}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${utente.nome}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${utente.cognome}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${utente.email}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${utente.genere}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```